# wacom intuos tablet not detected for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, wacom

I'm sorry if similar questions to this have been asked before but I cannot resolve the problem.

To set up a wacom intuos tablet on ubuntu 16.04 I followed the steps in
https://linuxwacom.github.io/:

For the kernel driver https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Installing-input-wacom-from-source

- I downloaded and untared the latest input-wacom-0.46.0 release
- Then

`if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"`

which gives output

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking dependency style of gcc... none
checking if build path '/home/samuel/Downloads/input-wacom-0.46.0' has spaces... no
checking for kernel type... Linux
checking for linux-based kernel... yes
checking for kernel source/headers... /lib/modules/4.4.0-198-generic/build
checking kernel version... 4.4.0-198-generic
checking RHEL6 minor release... 0
checking RHEL7 minor release... 0
checking power supply version... v4.1+
checking abs accessor version... v2.6.36+
checking CONFIG_MODULE_SIG... y
checking CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_FORCE... 
checking CONFIG_LOCK_DOWN_KERNEL... 
checking CONFIG_LOCK_DOWN_IN_EFI_SECURE_BOOT... 
checking secure boot state... on
checking if modules must be signed... recommended
checking CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_HASH... sha512
checking for module signing hash algorithm... sha512
checking for kernel autogenerated key at /lib/modules/4.4.0-198-generic/build/certs/signing_key.pem... no
checking for kernel autogenerated cert at /lib/modules/4.4.0-198-generic/build/certs/signing_key.x509... no
checking for shim MOK key at /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv... no
checking for shim MOK cert at /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der... no
checking for rEFInd MOK key at /etc/refind.d/keys/refind_local.key... no
checking for rEFInd MOK cert at /etc/refind.d/keys/refind_local.cer... no
checking for module signing key... 
checking for module signing certificate... 
configure: WARNING: Kernel module signing is recommended but we are unable to find signing keys. Consider re-running configure with the options '--with-signing-key=<key>' and '--with-signing-cert=<cert>' set.

checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating 2.6.32/Makefile
config.status: creating 2.6.38/Makefile
config.status: creating 3.7/Makefile
config.status: creating 3.17/Makefile
config.status: creating 4.5/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
configure:
----------------------------------------
  BUILD ENVIRONMENT:
       linux kernel - yes 3.17
      kernel source - yes /lib/modules/4.4.0-198-generic/build

NOTE: The kernel drivers included in this package are only tested with the
X Wacom driver built from xf86-input-wacom. If you are running an X server
version older than 1.7, please use the drivers provided by the linuxwacom
package.

Please run 'make && make install'.
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/samuel/Downloads/input-wacom-0.46.0'
Making all in 3.17
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/samuel/Downloads/input-wacom-0.46.0/3.17'
    Building input-wacom drivers for 3.17 kernel.
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-198-generic/build M=/home/samuel/Downloads/input-wacom-0.46.0/3.17
make[3]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-198-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 2 modules
make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-198-generic'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/samuel/Downloads/input-wacom-0.46.0/3.17'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/samuel/Downloads/input-wacom-0.46.0'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/samuel/Downloads/input-wacom-0.46.0'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/samuel/Downloads/input-wacom-0.46.0'
Making install in 3.17
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/samuel/Downloads/input-wacom-0.46.0/3.17'
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-198-generic/build M=/home/samuel/Downloads/input-wacom-0.46.0/3.17 modules_install mod_sign_cmd=''
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-198-generic'
  INSTALL /home/samuel/Downloads/input-wacom-0.46.0/3.17/wacom.ko
/bin/sh: 1: /lib/modules/4.4.0-198-generic/extra/wacom.ko: Permission denied
  INSTALL /home/samuel/Downloads/input-wacom-0.46.0/3.17/wacom_w8001.ko
/bin/sh: 1: /lib/modules/4.4.0-198-generic/extra/wacom_w8001.ko: Permission denied
  DEPMOD  4.4.0-198-generic
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-198-generic'
mkdir -p /etc/depmod.d
echo "override wacom * extra" > /etc/depmod.d/input-wacom.conf
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/bin:/sbin" depmod -a 4.4.0-198-generic
/usr/sbin/update-initramfs -u -k 4.4.0-198-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-198-generic
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/samuel/Downloads/input-wacom-0.46.0/3.17'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/samuel/Downloads/input-wacom-0.46.0'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/samuel/Downloads/input-wacom-0.46.0'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/samuel/Downloads/input-wacom-0.46.0'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/samuel/Downloads/input-wacom-0.46.0'
```

Suggesting something wrong with the keys but was not sure how to change this..

Then to build X-driver https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Building-The-Driver

`sudo sh -c "apt-get update && apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-wacom$(dpkg -S $(which Xorg) | grep -Eo -- "-hwe-[^:]*")"`

The wacom tablet seems to appear under usb devices https://medium.com/@microaeris/setting-up-wacom-tablets-with-ubuntu-16-04-d7277e4a595d

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2b91 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:5834 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 056a:0376 Wacom Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But `xsetwacom --list devices` returns nothing and it says no tablet detected in ->settings ->wacom tablet.

Any help to sort this would be much appreciated.

Comment: The input-wacom instructions say to run `grep "" /sys/module/wacom*/version` with your tablet attached to verify the driver version. Please add the output of that command to your question.

Comment: @jigpu Running that (with or without tablet attached) gives `grep: /sys/module/wacom*/version: No such file or directory` However `modinfo wacom | grep version` gives `version:        v2.00-0.46.0
srcversion:     146F5893E6D6270218497D0
vermagic:       4.4.0-198-generic SMP mod_unload modversions `

Comment: If the tablet was connected and showing up in lsusb when you ran that command, the message indicates the Wacom driver is not loaded. Please now run `modinfo wacom | grep -E "filename|version"` to verify the driver is installed. Also run `dmesg | grep -i lockdown` to check if secure boot is preventing the driver from being loaded.

Comment: @jigpu To `modinfo wacom | grep -E "filename|version` I get `filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-198-generic/extra/wacom.ko
version:        v2.00-0.46.0
srcversion:     146F5893E6D6270218497D0
vermagic:       4.4.0-198-generic SMP mod_unload modversions ` And `dmesg | grep -i lockdown` returns nothing

Comment: The output from these two commands looks normal as well. You may still consider temporarily disabling Secure Boot in your BIOS "just in case" (see https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Secure-Boot#enabling-and-disabling-secure-boot) since I am not 100% sure if the lockdown message is generated on Ubuntu 16.04.

EDIT: I would also strongly suggest filing an issue at https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/issues/ and attaching the output from their sysinfo script: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linuxwacom/wacom-hid-descriptors/master/scripts/sysinfo.sh

Comment: @jigpu I temporarily disabled Secure Boot in your BIOS following https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Secure-Boot#enabling-and-disabling-secure-boot and now the tablet seems to have worked! Would you consider this a complete solution or should I file an issue as well as you suggested?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118389/discussion-between-sam-forbes-and-jigpu).